# Date formatter returning null in some cases (after 12:59:59)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdateformatter

I am receiving a JSON response as this.

```
{
        0 = 50;
        1 = 1;
        2 = 4;
        3 = "08:51:00";
        4 = "20:51:00";
        Id = 50;
        day = 4;
        endTime = "20:51:00";
        openTime = "08:51:00";
        venId = 1;
```

and I am using date formatters to convert string to date and then to appropriate string format by using this code.

```
NSDateFormatter * DateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

NSDateFormatter * recevingDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[recevingDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm aa"];

NSDate * openTime = [DateFormat dateFromString:[[_arrHoursOfOpr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"openTime"]];
NSDate * endTime = [DateFormat dateFromString:[[_arrHoursOfOpr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"endTime"]];
NSLog(@"the start time and end time is %@, %@", openTime, endTime);
objCell.txtDay.text =  [_arr_weekdays objectAtIndex:[[[_arrHoursOfOpr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"day"] integerValue]];
objCell.txtStartTime.text = [recevingDateFormatter stringFromDate:openTime];
objCell.txtEndTime.text =[recevingDateFormatter stringFromDate:endTime];
```

but somehow "openTime" is getting converted and "endTime" is returning null.

This is happening for all the strings which are above 12:59:59 i.e starting from time 13:00:00.

How can i fix that issue and support times later than 12:59:59?

Comment: That's not the JSON response that you receive. That's the output of an NSLog statement, with much of the information gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hh` indicates hours in the range of [1-12].

> Hour [1-12]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match the 12-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (h or K); it should not match a 24-hour-cycle format (H or k). Use hh for zero padding.

In particular the "it should not match a 24-hour-cycle format" is important for you, because you actually want to explicitly match the 24-hour clock.

**You need to use `HH` to support 13+ hours**:

> Hour [0-23]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match the 24-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (H or k); it should not match a 12-hour-cycle format (h or K). Use HH for zero padding.

See the [unicode docs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Assuming you are using standard date formats in your JSON, it's also very important to explicitly set the locale on the NSDateFormatter, otherwise date parsing can fail if the user has their clock set to 12 hour rather than 24 hour format, like this:

`[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`